# How to add TextChangeListener at RichTextArea in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, richtextarea

```
TextField searchField = new TextField();
searchField.addTextChangeListener(new TextChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {
        updateCharecterLeft();
    }
});
```

i want a RichTextArea instead of searchField . but RichTextArea doesnt have addTextChangeListener. pls help

Answer (score 0):

[RichTextArea](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/RichTextArea.html) has addValueChangeListener() method instead, which is inherited from [AbstractField](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#addValueChangeListener(com.vaadin.data.Property.ValueChangeListener)).

```
RichTextArea richTextArea = new RichTextArea();
    richTextArea.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
            updateCharecterLeft();
        }
    });
```

Comment: ya but this doesn't work when i type each character. work only change of focus. I want to show remaining character in a separate label. each time user input character on it.

Comment: try setting setImmediate(true);

Comment: SetImmidiate true work with change of focus. Not in every keystroke from keyboard. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
textArea.setImmediate(true);
textArea.setTextChangeEventMode(TextChangeEventMode.EAGER);
textArea.addTextChangeListener(new TextChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {
            // use event.getText() 
        }       
});
```